# How to convert sequence of image file to video using c programming?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am working on a V4L2 camera driver.The webcam taking number of sequence of image files.Now I want to convert it into video (mp4) file.How it is possible using FFMPEG/GSTREAM using pure c source code instead of ubuntu terminal command ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please ask a specific questions when you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

GStreamer can be used to write applications using C. There are application guides available on their documentation site. But you need few extra topics related GObject as well to start using the framework.

I would recommend to go through their documentation site.
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/index.html?gi-language=c

It is not that hard if you read through the documentation and they have lots of plugins available to to achieve quite lots of things related to audio/video processing.